# Admob click -> App crashes and nothing happens

Tags: android, admob

i implemented two Admob Ads in two XML Layouts. They are loading and showing but when i click on the ads, my app crashes (maybe because my onPause method includes `System.exit(0);` , Otherwise it crashed on Resume.

But the click on the admob ad doesn't start anything else. I'm not getting redirected to the market or to the browser.

I click on it, my app finishes and nothing else happens.

Any ideas? I followed the google developers guide for implementing, this is the code inside my app:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView2);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

---

#### Solved

The problem was like I thought the onPause Method which killed all java instances of my app, thats why the app crashed immediately and the ad wouldn't work. By fixing my problems with the onPause and on Resume Methods, I fixed the problems mentioned above.

Comment: `my onPause method includes System.exit(0);` don't do that

Comment: For us to be able to help you, we need to see what the error message that you're getting is. Please edit your question and add it in.

Comment: i dont wanted to do that but it was the only way my app didn't crashed when i pushed the home button and tried to reconnect, but you guys are right, i have to work on this...

Answer (score 1):

Try removing System.exit(0);

Can you be more specific about error, connect phone though adb monitor error and post it.Check most common errors below

1) have you added the activity in manifest file ??,  If not add this in manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

2) meta data to your application

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

3) I think you added these permissions because without these ads won't pop up, but since you said you got the ads, this might not be your case

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Check here for more details :- https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start